# Google app engine + python (django) deployment error: Error loading MySQLdb module

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, mysql-python

I am creating an app on Google App Engine. I am using Django 1.4 and Python 2.7. Everything works fine on localhost. But after deployment it is not running, I keep getting this on admin logs:

```
    2012-12-15 15:02:41.870

    /base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/lib/cacerts/urlfetch_cacerts.txt missing; without this urlfetch will not be able to validate SSL certificates.

    W 2012-12-15 15:02:41.870

    No ssl package found. urlfetch will not be able to validate SSL certificates.

    E 2012-12-15 15:02:46.086

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 196, in Handle
        handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
      File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 266, in _LoadHandler
        __import__(cumulative_path)
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cloudwallforever/1.363864476397206865/djangoappengine/main/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
        setup_env()
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cloudwallforever/1.363864476397206865/djangoappengine/boot.py", line 82, in setup_env
        setup_logging()
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cloudwallforever/1.363864476397206865/djangoappengine/boot.py", line 130, in setup_logging
        if not settings.DEBUG:
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cloudwallforever/1.363864476397206865/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
        self._setup()
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cloudwallforever/1.363864476397206865/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
        self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cloudwallforever/1.363864476397206865/django/conf/__init__.py", line 87, in __init__
        mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cloudwallforever/1.363864476397206865/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
        __import__(name)
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cloudwallforever/1.363864476397206865/settings.py", line 6, in <module>
        import django.db.backends.mysql.base
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cloudwallforever/1.363864476397206865/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 14, in <module>
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
    ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

Any ideas why it is happening?

Comment: Are you aware that you can't use MySql on App Engine? At least not on App Engine itself, you could use a mysql server somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to delete one import from MYSQL.

Answer (score 7):

The 'Django Support' documentation hints at the solution, but doesn't make it explicit:

> Since the standard django.db.backends.mysql backend uses MySQLdb internally, app.yaml must reference MySQLdb in the list of libraries.

Adding the following to `app.yaml` seems to fix the ImportError:

```
libraries:
- name: MySQLdb
  version: "latest"
```

Note that MySQLdb is not currently included in the list of [available third party libraries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27). I tried it on a whim and it seems to have fixed the issue for me, YMMV.[enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django)

Comment: P.S I'm aware that the OP was not intending to be using MySQL on AppEngine, but with Cloud SQL this is now a supported configuration (in Preview, currently). This SO question is a top Google search hit for 'appengine ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb', so hopefully this solution will be of use to others who actually ARE trying to use MySQLdb on AppEngine.

Comment: This did not fix the problem for me. I still get the `ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb` error on my GAE dev server. I tried `latest` as well as `1.2.5`.

Answer (score 2):

As the [Cloud SQL docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django) clearly state, you should be using `''google.appengine.ext.django.backends.rdbms'` as your database engine setting.

Comment: Just to avoid confusing others - that is not the setting for dev server - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django#development-settings says `django.db.backends.mysql` for production

Answer (score 0):

If it's not working after adding the following to your app.yaml:

```
libraries:
- name: MySQLdb
  version: "latest"
```

...then take the following steps:

1. Ensure MySQLdb is installed `pip install mysql-python` on Mac
2. Ensure the GAE devserver is pointing to your virtualenv/pip'd python 2.7 installation vs. Mac/*nix's default version as pip may not have installed it there. I resolved `Can't find module: MySQLdb` by updating the GAE devserver to use: `/usr/local/bin/python2.7` e.g. in [GAE devserver preferences for Python Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsFaw.png)

Note: the preferences can be accessed through the application menus:

- If you're using Windows: look under `File > Preferences...`
- If you're using Mac, look under `GoogleAppengineLauncher > Preferences...`

Comment: Where is the GAE devserver preference pane?

Comment: They're under the application menus. I've edited the post to clarify this!

Comment: Is GoogeAppEngineLauncher a command line tool or does it have an actual GUI? I only remember installing the Google Cloud SDK to get GAE set up.